# Displaying data from 2d array and stringstream

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream, stringstream

I'm writing a program that reads data from a file that looks like:

```
W Z W Y W Y W W Y W Y Z W Z Y
Z W W W Y W Y W Z Y W Z W Y Y  
Z W Z Z Y Z Z W W W Y Y Y Z W
Z W Z Z Y Z Z W W W Y Y Y Z W 
Z W Z Z Y Z Z W W W Y Y Y Z W
```

These characters (W, Y, or Z) are parsed using a `stringstream` and stored in a 2D array that's 5x15. Now I'm having trouble **counting the amount of times that each character** **appears on each line**. I've tried multiple ways of achieving this by using counter variables in my function but I haven't gotten it so far. FYI, the idea is to then create a report to display this data for each line and then a total for all.

How can I achieve this then? (I can only use arrays for this assignment (no vectors, structures, or classes)). Thanks guys.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void fromFile(ifstream &, char items[][15], const int, const int, char);

int main() 
{
    ifstream in;
    in.open("file.txt");

    const int A_ROWS = 5, A_COLUMNS = 15;

    char items[A_ROWS][A_COLUMNS];
    char itemDetails;

    fromFile(in, items, A_ROWS, A_COLUMNS, itemDetails);

    in.close();
    return 0;
}

void fromFile(ifstream & in, char items[][15], const int A_ROWS, const int A_COLUMNS, char itemDetails)
{
    for (int rows = 0; rows < A_ROWS; rows++)
    {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < A_COLUMNS; columns++)
        {
            string theData = "";
            if (getline(in, theData))
            {
                stringstream str(theData);
                while (str >> itemDetails)
                {
                    items[rows][columns] = itemDetails;
                    // test to display all the data from the file properly
                    // cout << items[rows][columns] << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `columns` and `rows` are not being incremented as you read from the stringstream. Is it a requirement to use stringstream? It is much easier without it: use the ifstream directly.

Comment: **Solve a simpler version of the problem first.** Hard code a single line (e.g. "W Z W Y W Y W W Y W Y Z W Z Y") and write a function that will count the number of Ws.

Comment: @A.S.H It's not a requirement to use stringstream.

Comment: Then think about it. Dont use getline and stringstream, you only need `in >> items[rows][columns]`. Use `in.ignore()` to reject the space in-between.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple array to account for all the letters.
The alphabet has 26 letters (a-z), so I would create an array with a length of 26 where each position represents a letter.
You can then find the position of each letter in the array by subtracting 'a' from each letter. It would work pretty much like a map.

Here is a snippet:

```
int letters[26] =  {0};
letters['z' - 'a'] += 1; // letters[25], or 26th element.
```