# Summing rows of 2D array of characters

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a program that reads data from a file that looks like:

```
W Z W Y W Y W W Y W Y Z W Z Y
Z W W W Y W Y W Z Y W Z W Y Y  
Z W Z Z Y Z Z W W W Y Y Y Z W
Z W Z Z Y Z Z W W W Y Y Y Z W 
Z W Z Z Y Z Z W W W Y Y Y Z W
```

I'm storing these characters in a 2D array, and I need to get the total amount of Ws, Zs, and Ys on **each line** but my code is printing out the total for each letter across the entire file, instead of the total on each line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    ifstream in;
    in.open("file.txt");

    const int A_ROWS = 5, A_COLUMNS = 15;

    char items[A_ROWS][A_COLUMNS];

    // load 2D array with contents from file.
    for (int rows = 0; rows < A_ROWS; rows++)
    {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < A_COLUMNS; columns++)
        {    
            in >> items[rows][columns];
        }
    }

    //set counter for one letter
    int W = 0;
    for (int rows = 0; rows < A_ROWS; rows++)
    {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < A_COLUMNS; columns++)
        {    
            if (items[rows][columns] == 'W')
            {
                W++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << W; // this prints out the TOTAL amount of Ws in the entire file

    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the total of each letter per line? Thanks all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying data from 2d array and stringstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600984/displaying-data-from-2d-array-and-stringstream)

Comment: Display the total after you count everything in the row, and then reset the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the total of each letter per line? Thanks all.

Create three arrays to keep track of the counts of the letters in each line.

```
int wCounts[A_ROWS] = {0};
int yCounts[A_ROWS] = {0};
int zCounts[A_ROWS] = {0};
```

Keep the count of the letters in the arrays instead of in single variables.

For `W`, it will be:

```
if (items[rows][columns] == 'W')
{
    wCounts[rows]++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you can simply move your `W` output and reset to the outer loop:

```
//set counter for one letter
int W;
for (int rows = 0; rows < A_ROWS; rows++)
{
    W = 0;

    for (int columns = 0; columns < A_COLUMNS; columns++)
    {    
        if (items[rows][columns] == 'W')
        {
            W++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Row " << rows << ": " << W << endl;
}
```